# Find a value from certain columns within all tables in a database - dynamic sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop, dynamic-sql

Is there a way to do this with t-sql without using a cursor or a loop or temporary tables? Maybe by using dynamic sql?

I want to get the maximum value from the first column of each table in a database.

I use syscolumns to show me the names of all the tables and the name of the first column in each table.

So in the (non-working) example below I need to find a way to loop through syscolumns and use all the values for @tabname and @colname. Is there a way of doing that?

```
declare @tabname sysname;
declare @colname sysname;

SELECT 
name                                    as [column name],
object_NAME(id)                         as [table name],
(select max(@colname) from @tabname)    as [max col value]
from syscolumns             
where colorder = 1
```

Any help or tips appreciated.

Regards, Dave.

Comment: What a strange requirement. What actual use could this provide? To get the max value from the first column in each table would require dynamic sql. The answer provided by Kannan below does a great job of getting the column names. You would need to extend that with dynamic sql to get your values.

Comment: Thanks Sean. Yes, other peoples requirements are always very strange when shown out of context on a forum like this. Unfortunately I can't elaborate on the context due to security reasons.  I have all the column names and table names by using my very simple starting query of syscolumns where colorder = 1  (see it in the reply I gave to Kannan.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use query like this

```
;WITH cte
AS (SELECT
    object_id,
    MIN(column_id) mincolumnid
FROM sys.columns
GROUP BY object_id)
SELECT
    t.name,
    c.name
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c
    ON t.object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN cte ct
    ON c.object_id = ct.object_id
    AND c.column_id = ct.mincolumnid
```

Comment: This gets the columns names but not the values as the OP states.

Comment: Oh got it.. I mis-understood the question and thought i need to get the column names only, As you mentioned it will be a strange requirement we we might require to loop thru all the tables to get values

Comment: Yeah. Your query is an excellent starting point for the dynamic sql.

Comment: Thanks @Kannan.  I use this as my starting point:    SELECT 
    name         as [column name],
    object_NAME(id)       as [table name]
    from syscolumns    
    where colorder = 1